# jQuery prevAll displaying text in backward ordering

Tags: jquery, html, find

I'm trying to use jQuery to get all the paragraphs before the first h2 tag in my content. Here's the code I'm using:

```
$(".content").find("h2:first").prevAll().text()
```

Which is grabbing the content, although it's displaying it in backwards order. Example content:

```
<div class="content">
  <p>paragraph 1</p>
  <p>paragraph 2</p>
  <p>paragraph 3</p>
  <h2>First h2 tag</h2>
  <p>paragraph 4</p>
  <p>paragraph 5</p>
  <p>paragraph 6</p>
  <h2>Second h2 tag</h2>
</div>
```

The above code is outputting:

```
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
```

Is there any way of reversing this, so it's in the correct order? I have tried using nextAll using different codes, but it seems to grab all of my content, or not work at all lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dunno if following will work:

```
Array.prototype.reverse.call($(".content").find("h2:first").prevAll());
```

Comment: don't forget the .text() at the end (outside of the reverse call). You have to do this instead of just calling reverse() because the jquery result object doesn't keep all the native javascript array methods.

Comment: thank you :) 
I can see this has been answered in 2010, and I'm sure its still helping a lot of people like me

Answer (score 6):

We can just do this:

```
$(  $(".content h2:first").prevAll().get().reverse()  ).text();
```

**Note:** `[].reverse()` is a javascript array (here with DOM elements) and you need to make it a jQuery array wrapping with `$( ... )` like above; For example: `$( [].reverse() )`